# Double for loop with ifelse() is not working properly in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, na, class-factory

I am trying to run through each columns of my dataframe and convert "unknown" values to NAs. I tried the following code:

```
for (i in seq(length(df))) {
 for (j in seq(nrow(df))) {
      ifelse(df[,i][j] == "unknown", NA, df[,i][j])
 }
}
```

It, however, has not changed any values. The columns I am trying to alter are factors so I also tried:

```
for (i in seq(length(df))) {
 x <- class(df[,i])
 as.character(df[,i])
 for (j in seq(nrow(df))) {
      ifelse(df[,i][j] == "unknown", NA, df[,i][j])
 }
 class(df[,i]) <- x
}
```

to no avail. There is no error obtained and the code appears to run without problem; only the values remain as "unknown.

Comment: You may handle this when reading your data to R; please check the `na.strings` argument in `read.table`.

Comment: ifelse is *not* the same as if and else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try:

```
df[df == "unknown"] = NA
```

This assumes that all your columns are character and not factor.

Answer (score 2):

Running ifelse does not change the values of any of its arguments. You would have needed to assign the result back to the column of `df`. And doing it by row doesn't make any sense because ifelse is designed to be used on a vector, so instead it might be:

```
for (i in seq(length(df))) {
       df[,i] <- ifelse(df[,i] == "unknown", NA, df[,i] )
 }
}
```

Which still isn't optimal in light of the much more efficient strategy illustrated by @TimBiegeleisen, but at least you can study this to see how to improve your understand of using `for`-loops and `ifelse` when using R.